# How do I use other libraries in my RazorEngine templates?

Tags: winforms, razorengine

I have a template:

```
@using Team.Support.DateCalc
<h1>@Model.Username</h1>

<p>@Model.Address<br>
@Model.City, @Model.State @Model.Zip</p>

@Model.LastContacted.AddBusinessDays(3)
```

where `.AddBusinessDays()` is an extension method in the `Team.Support.DateCalc` lib which is referenced in the application.

This is my app config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="razorEngine" type="RazorEngine.Configuration.RazorEngineConfigurationSection, RazorEngine" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>

  <razorEngine>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="Team.Support.DateCalc" />
    </namespaces>
  </razorEngine>
</configuration>
```

This is the code in a winform project where I create the merged data:

```
PreviewWebBrowser.DocumentText = Razor.Parse(HtmlEditTextBox.Text, eo);
```

Comment: I've never used RazorEngine before, but I was able to find this, does it help at all? https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html.  From the sound of it, just referencing the assembly in the application isn't enough, it actually has to be _used_ in order for the assembly to be loaded.  If that's a problem, the code on the linked page can be used to manually bring in the assembly.

Comment: @BradleyUffner yeah, you have to create your own reference resolver to get the dll's in, that's what I ended up doing